# PHP Regex Cleaning of User Posts

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to clean up user submitted comments in PHP using regex but have become rather stuck and confused!

Is it possible using regex to:

1. Remove punctuation repeated more than twice so that:

   - `OMG it was AWESOME!!!!` becomes `OMG it was AWESOME!!`
   - `!!!!!!!!!!.........------` becomes `!!..--`
   - `!?!?!?` becomes `!?`
2. Remove duplicate words of phrases (for example a user has copied and pasted a message) so:

   - `spamspamspamspam` becomes `spam`
   - `I love copy and paste. I love copy and paste. I love copy and paste.` becomes `I love copy and paste.`
3. Remove collections of letters and spaces longer than say 10 letters in caps:

   - `I LOVE CAPITALS THEY ARE SO AWESOME` becomes `I love capitals they are so awesome`
   - `GOOD that sounds` stays the same
4. Any suggestions you have?

This is for a student system (hence the urge to at least try and tidy up what they post), although I do not wish to go as far as filtering it or blocking their messages, just "correct" it with some regex.

Thanks for your time,

---

Edit:

If it isn't possible using regex (or regex mised with other PHP) how would you do it?

Comment: Don't try to solve communication problems technically. You can only fail.

Comment: i think the bug is at the user level in this case

Comment: I agree re Wadih's comment, I am not looking to fix this problem (I don't think I can), just try to enforce some sensible rules that help "cap" it so to speak!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1:

```
// same punctuation repeated more than 2 times
preg_replace('#([?!.-])\1{2,}#', '$1$1', $string);

// sequence of different punctuations repeated more than one time
preg_replace('#([?!.-][?!.-]+?)\1+#', '$1', $string);
```

2:

```
// any sequence of characters repeated more than one time
preg_replace('#(.{2,}?)\1+#', '$1', $string);
```

3:

```
// sequence of uppercase letters and spaces
function tolower_cb($match) {
        return strtolower($match[0]);
}
preg_replace_callback('#([A-Z ]{10,})#', 'tolower_cb', $string);
```

Try it here: http://codepad.org/iQsZ2vJ0

Comment: +1 Very well thought out answer. Though for #2 I'd use `(.+?)` and not `(.*?)`. to prevent it from matching 0 occurences.

Comment: These are really, really good, very impressed with how simplistic yet effective they are, will definitely bookmark this page!

Comment: I can only think of the "Words words words" line in Hamlet

Comment: The regex are right, but I wouldn't use them on a real user input. For instance, #1 would transform "Oh... no!" into "Oh.. no!" and #2 "cocoa" into "coa" or "pom pom pi dou" into "pom pi dou". And "titicaca lake"?

Comment: This is true, perhaps I shall not use them then, I do agree with the points you are raising!

Answer (score 2):

A good rule of thumb is to never, ever try and "fix" user input. If a user wants to type 4 exclamation points after a sentence then allow it. There is no reason not too.

You should be more concerned with injection attacks then things like this.